# What is edge extrude technique for modeling

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

I recently read a word call edge extrude method of modeling but content I can't find on internet please help me to get there and which aspects of areas are we can use this method of modeling.

Comment: can you please tell a little bit more on what it is and what is the purpose?

Comment: You simply select an edge, press E to start extrusion. Extrusion adds a surface between starting edge and extruded edge. I'd suggest looking for sources on 'blender 3d extrusion' to give you a better understanding.

Comment: In which area we can use this technique read we can use this for face modeling and for achieve specific pattern but want to More areas of use

Comment: Have you tried Blenders built in Extrude Edges?(see @internetofmine comment above) Does it work for you in the manor you require? I have seen many examples of using Extrude from Edges to create specific geometry in Blender.

Comment: ..often used in combination with Shrinkwrap for retopology  ..  you could look up tutorials on that.. like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hEHtKH55Us)

Comment: Oh thanks I also was looking for this this technique is related to sculpting 